# Inserting selected row into mysql

Tags: java, mysql

**EDITED** I´ve changed the SQL code and it works, but I get the exception:
"cannot set a null tableModell

I´ve seen many very similar examples but not the one I need.
Therefore here we go:

It´s simple - In a InternalFrame I insert Code, ProjectName, Teamleiter, Description and click "Teilnehmer" to list all members of all projects from a table "tbl_teinehmer". Just the Lastname is shown.

So, I insert the correspondent data into the fields, list the projectmembers and select the members who will take part of this new project I´m creating.

In order to insert the data and the **selected row** from "teilnehmer" into a **new Table**:

```
   private void buttonAnlegenActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
            String data = tbl_teilnehmer.getValueAt(tbl_teilnehmer.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString();
            String sql = "INSERT INTO TBL_PROJETO (PROJEKT_ID, PROJEKTNAME, TEAMLEITER, BESCHREIBUNG,**TEILNEHMER**)"; //now it works but I get the exception: cannot set a null TableModell.
                    + "  VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)";
            menu = new HauptMenu();
            try{
                PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                pst.setString(1, ct.getText());
                pst.setString(2, nt.getText());
                pst.setString(3, st.getText());
                pst.setString(4, beschreibungText.getText());
                pst.setString(5, data);
                pst.execute();
                menu.listaProjetos();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Projekt added to Database");

            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println(e);
            }
            try{
                conn.close();
            }catch(SQLException ex){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
            }
            ct.setText("");
            nt.setText("");
            st.setText("");

        }
```

This is the error:

```
  java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (5 > number of parameters, which is 4).
```

Maybe the problem is by PreparedStatemend declaration.
I´ve set

```
pst.setString(5, data);
```

as it would recognize the selected row from the variable data but I guess it´s wrong.

Comment: Try removing `pst.setString(5, data);` and re-run your program

Comment: Change `VALUES(?,?,?,?,data)` or `VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for helping me!
**I solved the problem first by changing the SQL declaration:**

First at **I´ve placed '"+data+"'**, which is an placeholder(If I´m not mistaken) **but I wanted to set the selected row into the respective column in DB**.
Therefore I´ve changed it to the **columnname**: TEILNEHMER and set another questionmark '**?**' as **VALUE**.

It worked but I still got the error>> **cannot set a null TableModel**
and under this error >> **Unsupported collation 'Latin7'**  or smth like that.

So I´ve set the Collation of my table from Lati7 to TableDefault and now it works entirely.

**THANK YOU ALL AGAIN FOR HELPING ME!**

Answer (score 1):

do it as follows

```
 pst.setString(0, ct.getText());
 pst.setString(1, nt.getText());
 pst.setString(2, st.getText());
 pst.setString(3, beschreibungText.getText());
 pst.setString(4, data);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no placeholder for `5th parameter` in your `sql` query:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO TBL_PROJETO (PROJEKT_ID, PROJEKTNAME, TEAMLEITER, BESCHREIBUNG,'"+data+"')"
             + "  VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)";
```

Comment: @bruno-kommers Replace "String sql" line in your code to as shown in Answer.

Comment: It worked just by adding sql from '"+data+"' to the column Teilnehmer set in database.

Comment: now it "works" BUT ... I still have a problem: java.lang.IllegalArgunmentException: cannot set a null TableModel